# Android camera program error -2147483648

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to learn how to take photos using the camera. I am referring to [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html) and trying to implement the `MakePhotoActivity` class. When I run the app on my phone, the app starts normally.  Ideally, clicking on the "MakePhoto" button should capture an image and save it to my SD card. However, when I click on the "MakePhoto" button my application doesn't do anything. On checking the logcat, I `error -2147483648` in it. Can anybody tell what's happening here and how do I resolve this error?

EDIT:

Here is the logcat:

```
03-16 13:16:03.608: I/Process(7907): Sending signal. PID: 7907 SIG: 9
03-16 13:16:11.108: D/TextLayoutCache(8052): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
03-16 13:16:11.148: D/libEGL(8052): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
03-16 13:16:11.158: D/libEGL(8052): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-16 13:16:11.158: D/libEGL(8052): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-16 13:16:11.158: D/libEGL(8052): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-16 13:16:11.198: D/OpenGLRenderer(8052): Enabling debug mode 0
03-16 13:16:28.308: D/MakePhotoActivity(8052): Camera found
03-16 13:16:28.498: E/Camera(8052): Error -2147483648
```

I also tried seaching my SD card for any pictures but couldn't find any.

I tried to debug the program. Here's what I get:

```
03-16 14:23:13.949: W/dalvikvm(11426): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
```

Edit 2:

Ok. I am just printing out the uncaught exception using `e.printStackTrace();`
So, the logcat appends following in the log:

```
03-16 14:39:09.589: W/System.err(12863): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 14:39:09.599: W/System.err(12863):    at edu.gatech.makephotoactivity.MakePhotoActivity.onClick(MakePhotoActivity.java:43)
03-16 14:39:09.599: W/System.err(12863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 14:39:09.599: W/System.err(12863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 14:39:09.599: W/System.err(12863):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3058)
03-16 14:39:09.599: W/System.err(12863):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
03-16 14:39:09.599: W/System.err(12863):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
03-16 14:39:09.599: W/System.err(12863):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-16 14:39:09.599: W/System.err(12863):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-16 14:39:09.609: W/System.err(12863):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 14:39:09.609: W/System.err(12863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
03-16 14:39:09.609: W/System.err(12863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 14:39:09.609: W/System.err(12863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 14:39:09.609: W/System.err(12863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-16 14:39:09.609: W/System.err(12863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-16 14:39:09.609: W/System.err(12863):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So, I am getting a `NullPointerException`. My guess is that the `getDir()` function isn't returning anything. However, I am not sure. Any suggestions why I might be getting the exception and how do I get rid of it?

EDIT 3:

Now, I am trying to debug the program again. I get a message from the Class File Editor saying `Source Not Found. The source attachment does not contain source for ClassLoader.class`. I can put the details here but it would get too long. Apparently my code isn't able to find the `PhotoHandler` class . How do I get Eclipse to find class in same package?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get why I was getting that error and how to solve it. I also didn't get why eclipse wasn't able to find the `PhotoHandler` class during the run time. However, @JoxTraex's suggestion to use the implicit camera application intent was useful. So I had the removed the separate `onClick` function and added the following code in my `onCreate` method:

```
findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {    

      try {
          Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          startActivityForResult(i, RET_CODE);
      }    
      catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
});
```

I also added the following mehod to my `MakePhotoActivity` class

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if(resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

```
  switch(requestCode){
  case RET_CODE:
      Uri u = data.getData();      *//This gives the URI where the image is saved*
      /*
        FETCH THE PHOTO USING THE URI AND DO WHATEVER OPERATION YOU WANT WITH THE PHOTO (IN MY CASE SENDING IT OVER THE NETWORK)
      */
      break;
  default:
      break;
  }
```

}

and made appropriate changes to the XML file.

Although, this is not an answer to my question I am just posting it so that it might be useful to someone.